# I want to go thought list with if to check if multiple elements are equal to that I want

Tags: python

I want to do something like that:

```
if board[0:2] == choice:
    #the code here
```

So the thing I want is to go through the elements from 0 to 2 and to check if they are equal to 'choice' but I don't know how to do that.
  Please help!

Comment: the keyword is `for loop`

Comment: Do you want to know if *all* the elements in that slice (which only includes board[0] and board[1], not board[2]) are equal to choice or if *any* of them are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all([b == choice for b in board[0:2]]):
   ...
```

This compares each item in your array and creates a new array of True/False values.  Then `all()` returns True only if all the items in the new array are True (ie. they matched your `choice`).

Comment: you dont need the `[]`, `all` works for generators as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in board[0:2]:
    if item==choice:
        #the code here
```

Answer (score 1):

If your elements are hashable use a `set`:

```
st = set(choice)

if st.issuperset(board[0:2]):
```